# What is the equivalent of IE's removeNode

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

IE's removeNode
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536708(VS.85).aspx

helps me to decide whether I would like to remove childNodes or not.

I would like to know whether the same exists for Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari. If not, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't want just just copy code over, give this a read: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums//showthread.php?p=947385

Edit (but I, pst, have no shame -- code from above link ;-)

```
if ( window.Node )
Node.prototype.removeNode = function( removeChildren )
{
    var self = this;
    if ( Boolean( removeChildren ) )
    {
        return this.parentNode.removeChild( self );
    }
    else
    {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents( self );
        return this.parentNode.replaceChild( range.extractContents(), self );       
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this to remove a node in IFrame, and getting error. However, in the document itself, it is working great. The error is "targetElementinIframe.removeNode is not a function".

Comment: @Hoque that might be because the function is only defined in the parent document, not in the document inside the iframe.

Comment: Why the `var self = this;`?

Answer (score 2):

No, `.removeNode()` is not a standard method and it does not exist outside IE.

If you are looking for `removeNode`'s functionality of promoting element's children up a level (an optional boolean argument), you have to do it manually.

However, with jQuery it is easy:

```
$(elToRemove).replaceWith($(elToRemove).children());
```